# Remove elements of array when matching data between multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays of similar data, they have common property `id`.

I am wanting to remove entries from the first array if they don't also appear in the second... Is there a simple way to do this?

My arrays look like this:

```
$billing = [
  ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'one'],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'two'],
  ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'three']
];

$dbdata = [
  ['id' => '1', 'spanish' => 'uno'],
  ['id' => '3', 'spanish' => 'tres']
];
```

I am currently cycling through them for other data purposes like this:

```
foreach($billing as &$bill) {
  foreach($dbdata as $db) {
    if ($bill['id'] == $db['id']) {
       // Do some data manipulation here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where both datas coming from ? if both come from DB and have any relation you can sort out this there

Comment: They are not both from DBs, unfortunately.

Comment: is there any relation between them ?

Answer (score 0):

[array_udiff](https://php.net/array_udiff)

```
$billing = [
    ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'one'],
    ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'two'],
    ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'three']
];

$dbdata = [
    ['id' => '1', 'spanish' => 'uno'],
    ['id' => '3', 'spanish' => 'tres']
];

$filtered = array_udiff($billing, $dbdata, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['id'] === $b['id']) return 0;
    return ($a['id'] > $b['id']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Which will give you

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => two
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution by using `array_uintersect` along with the `spaceship` operator within the callback, something like:

```
uintersect($billing, $dbdata, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] <==> $b['id'];
}
```

However, it appears that this was introduced within PHP 7 but my codebase is not that advanced...

So I found a solution that worked - I guess it is the long-winded version of the spaceship:

```
uintersect($billing, $dbdata, function ($bill, $db) {
   if ( $bill['id'] == $db['id']) return 0;
   return ( $bill['id'] > $db['id']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: `uintersect()` is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

It took two steps for me.

1. Taking array difference for id key between a1 and a2 returns difference array.
2. Applying array_filter to a1 and searching values from array of step 1.

This code will get only values from a1
P.S. You may need to reset array keys for $a1 after filter.

```
$a1 = [
  ['id' => '1', 'name' => 'one'],
  ['id' => '2', 'name' => 'two'],
  ['id' => '3', 'name' => 'three'],
  ['id' => '4', 'name' => 'four']
];

$a2 = [
  ['id' => '1', 'spanish' => 'uno'],
  ['id' => '3', 'spanish' => 'tres']
];

$difference=array_diff(array_column($a1,'id'),array_column($a2,'id'));


$a1 = array_filter($a1, function($elem) use($difference){
    return array_search($elem['id'], $difference);
});
print_r($a1);
```